# Is there an way to appending a string to each list on first position?

Tags: python, list, data-structures, dataset

So the problem that i have is, i have a list (with all the elements inside it) and i wanna append an string (eg. 'watch') to every element in the list but in the first position.

```
list = ['sample', 'test', 'hello']
string = 'watch '

# the result should like this:
# ['watch sample', 'watch test', 'watch hello']
```

I've been try several times. But still, it's always give an error message.
Is there an way to solve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
l = ['sample', 'test', 'hello']
string = 'watch '

output = [string + i for i in l]

print(output)
>>> ['watch sample', 'watch test', 'watch hello']
```

Note that I use `l` rather than `list`. In general you shouldn't overload built in terms like that.